# Сложное предложение двойной вложенности с союзом "но"

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение

Допустим, есть предложение: *Революция уже свершилась, но страна ещё жила старыми порядками и люди не чувствовали перемен.*

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и"? На мысль о том, что не нужна, наводит тот факт, что обе грамматические основы второй части (*страна жила* и *люди не чувствовали*) благодаря противопоставлению "но" зависимы по смыслу от первой части (*революция свершилась*), и если разделить их запятой, то становится непонятным, слова *люди не чувствовали перемен* составляют вторую часть сложного предложения:

1. *Революция уже свершилась*; 2. (, но:) *страна ещё жила старыми порядками и люди не чувствовали перемен*;

или является самостоятельной третьей:

1. *Революция уже свершилась*; 2. (, но:) *страна ещё жила старыми порядками*; 3. (, и) *люди не чувствовали перемен* (этот фрагмент не противопоставляется первому).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение этой задачи известное, оно есть **у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133):** пункт 2, примечания.

```
 Примечания: 

 2. Противительный союз, после которого или перед которым 
 находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, 
 общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед и 
 ставится: Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, но ассамблея 
 была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал 
 присутствия своих приближённых (П.);
```

***Революция уже свершилась**, **НО** страна ещё жила старыми порядками,  и люди не чувствовали перемен.*

Другой вопрос будет потруднее: **а почему так?** Здесь нужно  подумать, поискать в источниках. Я могу предположить следующее: такие сочинительные союзы, как ***НО***, не могут считаться **общим элементом**. Они определяют **сочинительный** характер простых предложений, входящих в ССП, а эти предложения считаются **грамматически** независимыми.

Но вот **семантической** независимости (однородности) там **не так много.** Заданное предложение по семантике действительно состоит **из двух блоков:** раздел (противопоставление двух частей) идет по союзу ***НО***. Однако на письме мы это **не обозначаем.**